# How to get Atlassian Bamboo repository caching to work with docker?

Tags: docker, bamboo

Atlassian Bamboo repository caching causes issue with docker:

```
error: object directory $BAMBOO_HOME/xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache/8454c6d4af76ff5751c9e2ecf0bd2d2371695eec/.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates
error: Could not read d55f59e8de25d61533151b43092751e40269b31d
```

Note that we don't use docker agent because of permission issues, and the need for elevated privilege and capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache directory has to be added to docker as a volume using Bamboo's `$bamboo_git_cache_directory` environment variable:

```
docker run --rm -v $bamboo_git_cache_directory:$bamboo_git_cache_directory -v $(pwd):/workspace python:3.9 ...
```